# Jasmine 2.0 async done() and angular-mocks inject() in same test it()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, mocking, jasmine

My usual test case looks like

```
it("should send get request", inject(function(someServices) {
     //some test
}));
```

And Jasmine 2.0 async test should look like

```
it("should send get request", function(done) {
     someAsync.then(function(){
         done();
     });
});
```

How can I use both done and inject in one test?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

This should work; I ran into the same problem when I updated to Jasmine 2.0

```
it("should send get request", function(done) {
    inject(function(someServices) {
        //some async test
        done();
    })(); // function returned by 'inject' has to be invoked
});
```

Comment: For me this doesn't work. The code inside `inject` is never being called at all.

Comment: @WhiteAngel, the last time I had the problem you described, it was because some of the required dependencies for my app was missing from karma.conf.js's `files` list. It was impossible to debug this with `phantomJS` because it gives nowhere near enough error messages. If you haven't figured out the source of your problem, try using Chrome or FF as your test browser.

Comment: This didn't work for me. The return value of `inject` is a function, and needs to be called.

Comment: @WhiteAngel @dokkaebi In the code sample given, the method returned from `inject` is immediately invoked. This is super important! If you forget those two parens at the end, your test code will not be executed.

Answer (score 24):

An IMPORTANT note is the brackets after the `inject` call. Eg.

```
inject(function(someServices) {
   //some async test
   done();
})();  <-- these brackets here important.
```

If you look at the type of `inject`:

```
export declare function inject(tokens: any[], fn: Function): () => any;
```

You can see it returns a function, so you were getting no output because you forgot to call the function!!

If you think about it, it makes sense that it returns a function, because `it` takes a function!

So the extra parentheses should solve all problem!

Working Example:

```
  it('should allow you to observe for changes', function(done) {
    inject([GlobalStateService], (globalStateService: GlobalStateService) => {
      globalStateService.observe("user", storageType.InMemoryStorage, (user: string) => {
        expect(user).toBe("bla");
        done();
      });

      globalStateService.write({ user: "bla"}, storageType.InMemoryStorage);
    })();
  });
```

Comment: I think this is ok as an answer. In any case it would be too long for a comment.

Answer (score 11):

To add to the answer of @Scott Boring and to the comment of @WhiteAngel who mentionned that the code inside inject was never called.

This worked for me:

```
it("should send get request", function(done) {
    inject(function(someServices) {
       //some async test
       done();
    })();
});
```

Comment: Makes sense. The normal usage of `inject` is to pass its return value (`() => any`) in as the second argument to `it`, where it is called by jasmine. So we have to call the function returned by `inject` if we want it to run!

Comment: I get `inject is not a function` with this

Answer (score 2):

You could write the test like that:

```
describe("Some service'", function () {    
    var service;
    var data;

    beforeEach(function (done) {   

        module('app');

        inject(function (someService) {
            service = someService;
        });

        service
            .getData()
            .then(function(result) {
                data = result;
                done();
            });
    }); 

    it('should return a result', function () {  
        expect(data).toBeDefined();
    }); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For Angular 5.2.0: @scott-boring's approach did not work for me. What did work is using the `TestBed.get()` to get the services instead of `inject()`, as described in the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/testing#angular-testbed):

```
describe('TooltipComponent', () => {
  let component: TooltipComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TooltipComponent>;
  let myService: MyService;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    const myServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('MyService', ['calc']);

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ MyComponent ],
      providers: [
        {provide: MyService, useValue: myServiceSpy}
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();

    myService = TestBed.get(MyService);
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should render correctly', (done) => {
    component.render();

    setTimeout(() => {
      expect(myService.calc).toHaveBeenCalled();
      done();
    }, 1000);
  });
```