# How to wait for a callback to be executed inside a AngularJS directive unit test?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a simple directive that works fine (written with TypeScript but it does not really matter) that allows to get the content of files uploaded via `<input type="file">` and HTML5 File API.

The use is simple:

```
<body ng-controller="MyCtrl as ctrl">
  <input type="file" file-read="ctrl.readInputFile(data)">
</body>
```

callback readInputFile() is being called with the files content.

```
interface IFileReadScope extends angular.IScope {
  fileRead(data: any): void;
}

class FileRead implements angular.IDirective {
  restrict = 'A';
  scope = {
    fileRead: '&'
  };

  link = (scope: IFileReadScope, element: angular.IAugmentedJQuery) => {
    element.on('change', (e: Event) => {
      const files: FileList = (<HTMLInputElement> e.target).files;

      for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        const file = files[i];

        const reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = (e: Event) => {
          scope.$apply(() => {
            scope.fileRead({data: (<FileReader> e.target).result});
          });
        };

        reader.readAsText(file);
      }
    });
  };

  static factory(): angular.IDirectiveFactory {
    const directive = () => new FileRead();
    return directive;
  }
}

app.directive('fileRead', FileRead.factory());
```

And here the test for it:

```
describe('fileRead', () => {
  beforeEach(module('app'));

  let $compile: angular.ICompileService;
  let scope: any;

  beforeEach(inject((_$compile_, _$rootScope_) => {
    $compile = _$compile_;
    scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
  }));

  function compileTemplate(template: string): angular.IAugmentedJQuery {
    const el = $compile(angular.element(template))(scope);
    scope.$digest();
    return el;
  }

  it('should call a callback each time a file has been read', () => {
    const el = compileTemplate(
      '<input type="file" file-read="readInputFile(data)">'
    );

    const files = new Array<string>();

    scope.readInputFile = (data: any) => {
      files.push(data);
    };

    el.triggerHandler({
      type: 'change',
      target: {
        files: [
          new Blob(['data0']),
          new Blob(['data1'])
        ]
      }
    });

    scope.$digest();

    // Fails because it does not wait for scope.readInputFile() to be called
    expect(files.length).toEqual(2);
    expect(files[0]).toEqual('data0');
    expect(files[1]).toEqual('data1');
  });
});
```

The problem is that I don't know how to wait for `scope.readInputFile()` callback to be executed.

I've tried scope.$digest(), $rootScope.$digest(), $apply, Jasmine spyOn... I've also checked how popular directives do that. It seems like nobody do "that" :/

Any idea?

Edit:

Thanks to Hooray Im Helping and Matho, here the 2 possible solutions using Jasmine 2:

```
let files: string[];

beforeEach(done => {
  const el = compileTemplate(
    '<input type="file" file-read="readInputFile(data)">'
  );

  files = new Array<string>();

  scope.readInputFile = (data: any) => {
    files.push(data);
    if (files.length === 2) done();
  };

  el.triggerHandler({
    type: 'change',
    target: {
      files: [
        new Blob(['data0']),
        new Blob(['data1'])
      ]
    }
  });

  scope.$digest();
});

it('should call a callback each time a file has been read', () => {
  expect(files.length).toEqual(2);
  expect(files[0]).toEqual('data0');
  expect(files[1]).toEqual('data1');
});
```

And the more elegant one in this case:

```
it('should call a callback each time a file has been read', done => {
  const el = compileTemplate(
    '<input type="file" file-read="readInputFile(data)">'
  );

  const files = new Array<string>();

  scope.readInputFile = (data: any) => {
    files.push(data);
    if (files.length === 2) {
      expect(files[0]).toEqual('data0');
      expect(files[1]).toEqual('data1');
      done();
    }
  };

  el.triggerHandler({
    type: 'change',
    target: {
      files: [
        new Blob(['data0']),
        new Blob(['data1'])
      ]
    }
  });

  scope.$digest();
});
```

If `scope.fileRead()` is not executed inside the directive, then the test will fail:

```
FAILED fileRead should call a callback each time a file has been read
Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
```

So if the code breaks the unit test will fail => job done :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't use Jasime, i always use mocha + chaijs + sinon, but jasmine has the `done` function implemented as well, it should work like this:

```
it('async method', function(done){ 
//once we add the done param, karma will wait until the fn is executed

 service.doSomethingAsync()
  .then(function(){
    //assertions 
    // expect(result).to.be.something();
    done(); //Where we are telling karma that it can continue with the test
  }
  //Other assertions    
}
```

Using [`chai-as-promised`](https://github.com/domenic/chai-as-promised/):

```
it('async method', function(done){

 var result = service.doSomethingAsync();
 expect(result).to.eventually.be(something=;
  //Other assertions    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What version of Jasmine are you using?

If it's 1.3, you can use [`waitsFor` and `runs`](http://jasmine.github.io/1.3/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support) to wait a certain period of time then assert on the specs:

So

```
let files = new Array<string>();

scope.readInputFile = (data: any) => {
  files.push(data);
};

el.triggerHandler({
  type: 'change',
  target: {
    files: [
      new Blob(['data0']),
      new Blob(['data1'])
    ]
  }
});

scope.$digest();
```

becomes

```
let files = new Array<string>();

runs(function() {
    scope.readInputFile = (data: any) => {
        files.push(data);
    };

    el.triggerHandler({
        type: 'change',
        target: {
            files: [
                new Blob(['data0']),
                new Blob(['data1'])
            ]
        }
    });

    scope.$digest();
});
```

and

```
expect(files.length).toEqual(2);
expect(files[0]).toEqual('data0');
expect(files[1]).toEqual('data1');
```

becomes

```
waitsFor(function() {
    expect(files.length).toEqual(2);
    expect(files[0]).toEqual('data0');
    expect(files[1]).toEqual('data1');
}, "failure message", time_in_milliseconds);
```

If you're using Jasmine 2.0, you can use the [`done`](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support) function:

You'd move the code you're trying to test (and any set up code it depends on) to `beforeEach`, call the async code there, then notify the framework the async operation is done by calling the `done` method when the async code finishes. Your specs get run automatically get run after `done` called. I have never used this before (I'm still on 1.3) and I don't use Angular nor Karma, so I'm in a bit of unfamiliar territory.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27673009/92446), your `beforeEach` function should look like this:

```
beforeEach(function(done) {
    inject((_$compile_: angular.ICompileService, _$rootScope_: angular.IRootScopeService) => {
        $compile = _$compile_;
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
    });
    let el = compileTemplate('<input type="file" file-read="readInputFile(data)">');
    let files = new Array<string>();

    scope.readInputFile = (data: any) => {
        files.push(data);
    };

    el.triggerHandler({
        type: 'change',
        target: {
            files: [
                new Blob(['data0']),
                new Blob(['data1'])
            ]
        }
    });

    scope.$digest();

    done();
});
```

and your assertion should look something like:

```
it('should call a callback each time a file has been read by FileReader', (done) => {
    expect(files.length).toEqual(2);
    expect(files[0]).toEqual('data0');
    expect(files[1]).toEqual('data1');

    done();
});
```

Again, I don't use angular, TypeScript, or Karma, so you might need to tweak this. But this is the general idea; set everything up, run the async code, call `done` in set up, run assertions, call `done` in spec.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your `expect`ations in the callback function.

Comment: The test will silently fail the day the callback is not being called anymore => you just killed the whole purpose of testing code.