# Unknown provider: $stateProviderProvider in ui router testing

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angular-ui-router, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm trying to write test case for the Router in my angular app.I'm using `"angular-ui-router": "0.3.1"`,
Below is the setup and a sample test case :

```
beforeEach(angular.mock.module("ui.router"));
beforeEach(angular.mock.module("reactore"));
beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function ($rootScope, $stateProvider) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    route = $stateProvider.$new();

}));

it('should run tests', inject(function () {
    expect(null).toBeDefined();
}));
```

I'm initialising module `ui-router` and also specified `ui-router` file in karma.conf.js.But its giving error as

```
debug.html:38 Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.7/$injector/unpr?p0=%24stateProviderProvider%20%3C-%20%24stateProvider
    at http://localhost:9876/base/budget-ui/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:6:412
    at http://localhost:9876/base/budget-ui/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:43:84
    at Object.d [as get] (http://localhost:9876/base/budget-ui/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:40:344)
    at http://localhost:9876/base/budget-ui/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:43:146
    at d (http://localhost:9876/base/budget-ui/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:40:344)
    at e (http://localhost:9876/base/budget-ui/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:41:78)
    at Object.invoke (http://localhost:9876/base/budget-ui/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:41:163)
    at Object.workFn (http://localhost:9876/base/budget-ui/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:3078:20)
Error: Declaration Location
    at Object.window.inject.angular.mock.inject (http://localhost:9876/base/budget-ui/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:3040:25)
    at Suite.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9876/base/budget-ui/app/feature/budget/tests/unit/specs/budgetSpecs.js:27552:29)
    at http://localhost:9876/base/budget-ui/app/feature/budget/tests/unit/specs/budgetSpecs.js:27542:1
```

Please let me know if anyone has faced the similar issue..and steps took to overcome this error.
Thanks

Comment: check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29706931/2435473)