# getNumberOfUsers() subscription SPEC HAS NO EXPECTATIONS

Tags: angular

I keep getting the error:

> UserService unit tests getNumberOfUsers() SPEC HAS NO EXPECTATIONS
>   should return total number of users

When I have defined an expectation as below:

```
  describe('getNumberOfUsers()', () => {
    it('should return total number of users',
      inject([UserService], (userService) => {
        let noOfUsers = 0;
        userService.getNumberOfUsers().subscribe((result) => {
          noOfUsers = result.data.counter;
          expect(noOfUsers).toBeGreaterThan(0);
        });
    }));
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: The subscription is asynchronous (that's the whole point of it...) so there's no expectation reached until *after* the test finishes. [Read the docs.](https://angular.io/guide/testing#service-tests)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to supply jasmine's `DoneFn`

```
describe('getNumberOfUsers()', () => {
    it('should return total number of users', (done: DoneFn) => { // supply DoneFn
      inject([UserService], (userService) => {
        let noOfUsers = 0;
        userService.getNumberOfUsers().subscribe((result) => {
          noOfUsers = result.data.counter;
          expect(noOfUsers).toBeGreaterThan(0);
          done(); //call DoneFn
        });
    })(); // immediatly call inject function
  });
})
```

see for more information

- https://angular.io/guide/testing#component-with-async-service
- [Jasmine 2.0 async done() and angular-mocks inject() in same test it()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25274152/jasmine-2-0-async-done-and-angular-mocks-inject-in-same-test-it)

Comment: But whenever I use "done", it starts giving me this error:  Error: Timeout - Async function did not complete within 5000ms"